# How to build release apk from a bash script using terminal

Tags: android, bash, macos, unix

Here is the script from which I am trying to generate a release apk from terminal. I got this script to generate the release apk. But I am confused where to put the keystore.jks, username and password as given in the script. I am executing this script in mac. Here `$1` value is `app`. The script name is assemble.bash.

```
    LATEST_BUILD_TOOLS=$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/$(ls $ANDROID_HOME/build-tools | sort -n | tail -1)
ZIPALIGN=$LATEST_BUILD_TOOLSzipalign
APKSIGNER=$LATEST_BUILD_TOOLSapksigner

# define where we the built artifact is going to end up and where
# to put the signed apk if the artifact is an apk.
APK_DIRECTORY=$1/build/outputs/apk
AAR_DIRECTORY=$1/build/outputs/aar
UNSIGNED_APK_PATH=$APK_DIRECTORY/$1-release-unsigned.apk
APK_PATH=$APK_DIRECTORY/$1-release.apk

# assemble unsigned release apk
./gradlew -p $1 clean assembleRelease

if [ -d "$APK_DIRECTORY" ] ; then

  # prepare the unsigned release apk for signing
  $ZIPALIGN -v -p 4 $UNSIGNED_APK_PATH $APK_PATH

  # sign the release apk
  $APKSIGNER sign --ks /.keystore/keystore.jks --ks-pass file:/.keystore/ks-pass $APK_PATH

  # delete the unsigned release apk
  rm $UNSIGNED_APK_PATH

  echo "SUCCESS: Release APK has been assembled"
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your app's `build.gradle` like:

```
...    
signingConfigs {

   release {
       storeFile file(RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
       storePassword RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
       keyAlias RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
       keyPassword RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
   }
}

buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
}
....
```

And modify/create your `~/.gradle/gradle.properties` like:

```
RELEASE_STORE_FILE={/path/to/keystore}
RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=*****
RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=*****
RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=*****
```

Finally:

`./gradlew assembleRelease` will make a release Build of the apk.

separating the signing config into `gradle.properties` will make sure that your private key, alias and passwords are not leaked in your version control.

Comment: But I am not able to understand the commands in that. Can you please elaborate it. Specially `/.keystore/keystore.jks` and `file:/.keystore/ks-pass`

Comment: This method does not use `assemble.bash` script but does essentially the same. `gradlew` is a executable for building apk included in every project.